# VTK build using CMake, MinGW & Code::Blocks compilation errors

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, codeblocks, vtk

Win 10, x64

Hi I'm trying to build the VTK 8.1.0 using CMake, MinGW & Code::Blocks

CMake runs with no issues & creates a Code::Blocks project for building but
when I build I get the following compilation errors

> */||=== Build: all in VTK (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>
> C:\Users\qrb17230\Documents\OpenGL\VTK-8.1.0\Utilities\KWSys\vtksys\Directory.cxx||In
>   member function 'bool vtksys::Directory::Load(const string&)':|
>
> C:\Users\qrb17230\Documents\OpenGL\VTK-8.1.0\Utilities\KWSys\vtksys\Directory.cxx|118|error:
>   aggregate 'vtksys::Directory::Load(const string&)::_wfinddata_t data'
>   has incomplete type and cannot be defined|
>
> C:\Users\qrb17230\Documents\OpenGL\VTK-8.1.0\Utilities\KWSys\vtksys\Directory.cxx|122|error:
>   '_wfindfirst' was not declared in this scope|
>
> C:\Users\qrb17230\Documents\OpenGL\VTK-8.1.0\Utilities\KWSys\vtksys\Directory.cxx|132|error:
>   '_wfindnext' was not declared in this scope|
>
> C:\Users\qrb17230\Documents\OpenGL\VTK-8.1.0\Utilities\KWSys\vtksys\Directory.cxx|154|error:
>   aggregate 'vtksys::Directory::GetNumberOfFilesInDirectory(const
>   string&)::_wfinddata_t data' has incomplete type and cannot be
>   defined|
>
> C:\Users\qrb17230\Documents\OpenGL\VTK-8.1.0\Utilities\KWSys\vtksys\Directory.cxx|158|error:
>   '_wfindfirst' was not declared in this scope|
>
> C:\Users\qrb17230\Documents\OpenGL\VTK-8.1.0\Utilities\KWSys\vtksys\Directory.cxx|169|error:
>   '_wfindnext' was not declared in this scope|
>
> Utilities\KWSys\vtksys\CMakeFiles\vtksys.dir\build.make|187|recipe for
>   target
>   'Utilities/KWSys/vtksys/CMakeFiles/vtksys.dir/Directory.cxx.obj'
>   failed|
>
> CMakeFiles\Makefile2|226|recipe for target
>   'Utilities/KWSys/vtksys/CMakeFiles/vtksys.dir/all' failed|
>   C:\Users\qrb17230\Documents\OpenGL\VTK-bin\Makefile|128|recipe for
>   target 'all' failed|
>
> ||=== Build failed: 9 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 6
>   second(s)) ===| /*

[image]

I'm guessing that `_wfinddata_t` needs declaring in a header file? I'm at
the edge of my technical competence here so any help will be much
appreciated.

Comment: Seeing that there is no MinGW buld on VTK dashboards, https://open.cdash.org/index.php?project=VTK, I would suggest building with MSVC.

You can either do pur MSVC or MSVC console + ninja.

Comment: I tried to use Visual Studio as advised on the VTK Wiki but CMake refuses to accept that VS is installed.

Comment: Which version of visual studio ?

Comment: VS 15 it comes up as an option in Specify the Generator pull down & I have used it to compile & run programs so I know it is there & does work

Comment: OK I'm an idiot I had the wrong version of VS selected

Comment: Happy to help :)